# Ruby error: `initialize': No route to host - connect(2) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)

Tags: ruby, web-crawler

My Ruby program crawls certain pages automatically and works at my local (OS X).

But sometimes the error comes out:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': No route to host - connect(2) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:82:in `perform_request'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:40:in `block in call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:87:in `with_net_http_connection'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:32:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/signet-0.6.1/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:957:in `fetch_access_token'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/signet-0.6.1/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:983:in `fetch_access_token!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/signet-0.6.1/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:1000:in `refresh!'
```

My code is:

```
for num in 1..26
get_spreadsheet_id(sheet_id)
ws = @session.spreadsheet_by_key("#{@sheeturl}").worksheets[0]
for row in start_at..end_at

    #check internet connection and redo
    puts "network has problem #{Time.now.strftime("%m/%d %H:%M:%S")}" if internet_connectivity? == false
    redo if internet_connectivity? == false 

    CRAWL

    sleep rand(1...2)
end
sheet_id += 1
start_at = 2
end
```

Could you let me know what's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`No route to host` refers to a network problem. That means there is a connection issue somewhere between your computer and the remote host. That might be a permanent issue or just a hiccup that resolved itself after a second.

There is nothing you can do to solve the problem (beside getting a more reliable internet connection). But there is something you could do to minimize impact: You could retry multiple times if the connection fails.

That retry could be implemented easily within a `rescue` block. But if you also want to limit the number of returns (to avoid running into a loop), then the [`retryable` gem](https://github.com/nfedyashev/retryable) is helpful. With that gem, you could write something like this:

```
Retryable.retryable(
  :tries => 3,                         # try max 3 times
  :on    => Faraday::ConnectionFailed, # retry only on this error
  :sleep => lambda { |n| 4**n }        # wait 1, then 4 seconds between two tries
) do

  # CRAWL

end
```

Note that the `retryable` block raises the same exception if it still fails on the last retry. You might want to rescue from the error, log it, and continue with the next URL.